# Add Values until Threshold is reached, then go to next Threshold

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would need to add up values from D11 and downwards so that once the threshold in column E is reached, the remainder is assigned to the next threshold (so, once bucket A -E3- is filled, it goes on the next). As per below example, in D14 1 euro is assigned to Sector A and the other 32 to B. To reach the following threshold in E4 18 euros are needed, so that amount would be written in  D15.
I tried with (in D11) `=IF(SUM(OFFSET(C11,,,,1,1))<=E3,C11,E3-C11)` to start, thinking I could somehow find a way to count the height of the range, but I am stuck. Maybe a Macro would be a better option? If so, could someone guide me on how to start?

[image]

[EDIT] Although I have received a perfectly working answer, I tried to continue with the logic I was using above, yet there is the need of one help column and a number of references that gives headache, plus, it still needs more work. Simple is better!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The more effort you put in your question, the more chance people put effort into helping you.

Comment: If you have Office 365 you could look into SCAN(). I'd recommend not to go to the right with columns, but only downwards.

Comment: Post your data as data instead of picture helps generally. Also explain as good as possible why you expect certain results. (Why a next column for your result. How would it behave if 3 thresholds are met within one contribution? And again, do you have Office 365 and have you looked into SCAN()?

Comment: Honestly I think this question is fine (apart from copy-able data being better than image) and have upvoted it. It's clear enough for me to suggest an answer anyway (see below).

Answer (score 1):

I would keep things simple with a pull-down/pull across formula like this:

```
=MIN($C12-SUM($D12:D12),E$10-SUM(E11:E$11))
```

[image]

Can split across multiple sectors if required:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very simple and elegant!